# Replication between SQL server and Couchbase Lite

Tags: c#, sql-server, nosql

We have a main MS Sql server. This is the main data source that delivers and receives data to and from backend administration and (in development) mobile software. We need to make a connection to mobile. That is: the mobile application needs to be off- and online available. The data on mobile needs to reflect the state and data on the MS Sql server.

The original idea was / is to set up a Couchbase server, sync gateway (replication) and Couchbase lite (mobile). We need to communication with the MS Sql server to keep it all up to date.

But I was thinking about the weight all these services put on the server as one device. Are there any possibilities or ideas to cut out the middle man and let Couchbase lite communicate and replicate with the MS SQL server directly? Or is setting this up without Sync Gateway a bad idea?

Modelling and mapping is no problem. We have a fairly sound connection between our .NET Model and CBLite documents. It's just the whole replication process that's bothering me. I don't want to stress the resources on the server and keep the footprint of the cycle as minimal as possible

Comment: SQL Server is relational and Couchbase is document based (NoSQL).  You will need a middleman to convert the relational data to JSON and vice versa.